# Retrieve Documents from a Template

Tags: docusignapi

I created a template within my DocuSign developer Sandbox that contains one document. I'm using the C# SDK to try and send out an envelope to a user, based on a template.

Here's the code where I retrieve all of the templates.

```
TemplatesApi templateApi = new TemplatesApi(ApiClient.Configuration);

         EnvelopeTemplateResults templateResults = templateApi.ListTemplates(AccountID);
```

The issue I am having is the **EnvelopeTemplateResults**  does **NOT** have any documents associated with it.

When I use the REST API using POSTMAN, performing a GET to this URL, I can see that there's an **envelopeTemplateDefinition**, that has a Document on it, which is the one I want.

My question is, how, using the SDK API, can I get the **envelopeTemplateDefinition** ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the `ListTemplates` method include the Documents info, you have to set an Include parameter:

```
        var templatesApi = new TemplatesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
        var listTemplatesOptions = new TemplatesApi.ListTemplatesOptions { include = "documents" };
        var templateResults = templatesApi.ListTemplates(accountId, listTemplatesOptions);
```

If you are trying to get the Template Definition of a single template, the `templatesApi.Get()` method can be used with its own set of Include options:

```
        var getTemplateOptions = new TemplatesApi.GetOptions { include = "documents" };
        var templateDefinition = templatesApi.Get(accountId, templateId, getTemplateOptions);
```

Finally, if you're trying to get an actual PDF out of a specific template, that would be the `templatesApi.GetDocument()` method:

```
templatesApi.GetDocument(accountId, templateId, documentId);
```

Where DocumentId is the specific document you want to pull, or "Combined" if you want to pull all the documents in as a single PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, if you are using the v2 API, there's an endpoint:
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/documents/{documentId}

you can try it here - https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=TemplateDocuments&operations=get

the c# SDK inside TemplateAPI has GetDocument() and UpdateDocument() methods

Comment: Thanks Inbar.   I'm actually using the 2.1 API - but I'm using the C# SDK, instead of the API. 

I can get it to work using POSTMAN requests, but I can't see how to translate those API requests to  calls using the SDK.

Any idea?

Comment: Chris, what specific API call do you make using POSTMAN?

Comment: Hi, I am using this URL in POSTMAN:

{{baseUrl}}/templates/{{templateId}}

But, as you said above, when I add /documents to the end, I do / can see the templateDocuments- which is what I want to create / use / edit:

{{baseUrl}}/templates/{{templateId}}/documents

How can I mirror that API call (with /documents ) in the SDK?

Comment: Look at the TemplateAPI.cs UpdateDocument() method for this API